# SQL Error ORA-00904: invalid identifier

Tags: sql, oracle, ora-00904

I am trying to run this sql in Oracle SQL developer and I get the error of

```
ORA-00904: "I"."SZ": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 13 Column: 122
```

I am not sure what the issue is.  A friend of mine was able to run this sql he sent me with no problem.  I am using a VM as well.

Here is my SQL:

```
 SELECT 
                              oi.ID              AS ID, 
                              r.MARKET_CENTER_ID AS MARKET_CENTER_ID, 
                              SUBSTR(('0000' || r.MARKET_CENTER_ID),-4,4) AS MARKET_CENTER_NUMBER, 
                              r.ID               AS ROUTE_ID, 
                              r.NBR           AS ROUTE_NUMBER, 
                              oh.WORK_ORDER_DATE AS ORDER_DATE, 
                              c.NBR           AS CID, 
                              c.NAME             AS CUSTOMER_NAME, 
                              c.GARMENT_MARK     AS GID, 
                              oi.WEARER_NUMBER   AS WEARER_NUMBER, 
                              TRIM(oi.WEARER_FIRST_NAME || ' ' || oi.WEARER_LAST_NAME) AS WEARER_NAME, 
                              (CASE WHEN (i.ID) IS NULL THEN oi.ITEM_NUMBER ELSE i.CATEGORY || i.STYLE || i.COLOR || i.SZ END) AS ITEM_NUMBER, 
                              oh.INVENTORY_CODE             AS INVENTORY_CODE, 
                              NVL(oi.RTS_QTY,0)          AS EXPECTED_RTS, 
                              NVL(oi.RTS_RTS_QTY,0)      AS RTS_QTY, 
                              NVL(oi.RTS_RUIN_QTY,0)     AS RTS_RUIN, 
                              NVL(oi.RTS_ABUSE_QTY,0)    AS RTS_ABUSE, 
                              NVL(oi.RTS_RTW_QTY,0)      AS RTW, 
                              NVL(oi.RTS_LOSS_QTY,0)     AS RTS_LOSS, 
                              NVL(oi.RUIN_QTY,0)         AS RUIN, 
                              NVL(oi.LOSS_QTY,0)         AS LOSS, 
                              NVL(oi.ADJ_QTY,0)          AS ADJ, 
                              (CASE WHEN EC.ID IS NULL OR c.EC_STATUS <> 'A' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END)       AS EASY_CARE_LINE, 
                              (CASE WHEN oi.HH_MODULE = 'ExcessMerchandise' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS EXCESS_MERCH, 
                              ic.INV_DESC AS INV_DESC  
                            FROM route r 
                              INNER JOIN customer c 
                                ON c.ROUTE_ID = r.ID 
                              INNER JOIN order_header oh 
                                ON oh.CUSTOMER_ID = c.ID 
                              INNER JOIN order_item oi 
                                ON oi.ORDER_HEADER_ID = oh.ID 
                              LEFT JOIN inventory_code ic 
                                ON ic.INV_CODE = oh.INVENTORY_CODE 
                              LEFT JOIN customer_item ci 
                                ON ci.ID = oi.CUSTOMER_ITEM_ID 
                                   AND NOT oi.EXCHANGE_ITEM_ID IS NULL 
                              LEFT JOIN item i 
                                ON i.ID = ci.ITEM_ID 
                              LEFT JOIN customer_item ci2 
                                ON ci2.ID = oi.CUSTOMER_ITEM_ID 
                              LEFT JOIN item i2 
                                ON i2.ID = ci2.ITEM_ID 
                              LEFT JOIN ECARE_ITEMS EC 
                                ON EC.CUSTOMER_ID = c.ID 
                                  AND EC.ITEM_CATEGORY = i2.CATEGORY 
                                  AND EC.ITEM_STYLE = i2.STYLE 
                                  AND EC.ITEM_COLOR = i2.COLOR 
                                  AND EC.IE_FLAG = 'Y' 
                                  WHERE 

                             (CASE WHEN EC.ID IS NULL OR c.EC_STATUS <> 'A' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) = 1
                            AND oh.INVENTORY_CODE != '3G'
                                AND oh.STATUS_ID = 3;
```

Comment: There is probably no column named `SZ` on table `item`

Comment: run `desc item` and upload the output

Comment: Are "you" and "your colleague" different users (schemas) in the DB? Then it is possible the `item` table in your colleague's schema has a column `SZ` and your copy of the same table doesn't have it, or it has it with a different name. Separately, what is with the  "Buttion Disabled" close to the bottom of your code? (with "button" misspelled too). That wouldn't cause the error you reported, but it looks out of place all the same.

Comment: @mathguy we are pointing to the same schema/database.  I double checked with him and it works on his side.  That button misspelling is a comment that I forgot to take out here.

Answer (score -3):

One of the source column names is incorrect in the script.